# Different results using IQuery and Repository in Web App

Tags: nhibernate

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.  I'm just starting out with nHibernate and a little confused over this one.  It's running within a .Net Web Application.

Basically I've got 2 classes - Coupon and Publisher.

As a test, and to make sure NH was set up correctly, I accessed the PublisherRepository and pulled a publisher out by it's name.  That works fine and reports success.

```
IPublisherRepository repo = new PublisherRepository();
Response.Write(repo.GetByName("Publisher 5"));
```

As a second test, I then used the CreateQuery method to get all of the Publishers, like so:

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from CartManData.Domain.Publisher pub");
```

This returns no data - the list is empty.  Same goes using Linq:

```
session.Query<Publisher>().Where(x=>x.Name == "Publisher 4").ToList<Publisher>()
```

Using Sql Profiler I can see that the first test hits the database, and retrieves the set (called Coupons belonging to a Publisher) as lazy loading is off.  However, the second 2 approaches don't hit the database at all - and I'm stumped as to why.

Here's the mapping file for Publisher and Coupon.  They're embedded and I know they're working otherwise the repo wouldn't work either :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="CartManData"
                   namespace="CartManData.Domain">

  <class name="Publisher" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"></property>
    <property name="AddressLine1"></property>
    <property name="AddressLine2"></property>
    <property name="AddressLine3"></property>
    <property name="Town"></property>
    <property name="PostCode"></property>
    <property name="Telephone"></property>
    <property name="Email"></property>
    <property name="Enabled"></property>
    <property name="CommissionRate"></property>
    <set name="Coupons" cascade="none" lazy="false">
      <key column="PublisherId" ></key>
      <one-to-many class="Coupon" />
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And Coupons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="CartManData"
                   namespace="CartManData.Domain">

  <class name="Coupon">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"></property>
    <property name="EffectiveFrom"></property>
    <property name="EffectiveTo"></property>
    <property name="UnitPrice"></property>
    <property name="OriginalPrice"></property>
    <property name="CouponImage"></property>
    <property name="Enabled"></property>
    <property name="PublisherId" not-null="false"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Any help on this really appreciate - sure it's something I've missed.

Cheers,
Tony

**Additional Info**

The Session object is retrieved via a HttpModule, where the session object is bound to CurrentSessionContext.  That seems to be working fine as if you check to see if session is open, it reports it is.

PublisherRepository.GetByName() looks like this:

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Publisher))
                    .Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Eq("Name", name))
                    .UniqueResult<Publisher>();
            }
```

**Log4Net Output**

During the call via CreateQuery (the 2nd example above), this is what NHibernate is reporting:

```
2012-08-22 16:22:28,075 [15] DEBUG rollingFile - START of retrieval
2012-08-22 16:22:28,081 [15] DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache - unable to locate HQL query plan in cache; generating (from CartManData.Domain.Publisher pub)
2012-08-22 16:22:28,128 [15] DEBUG NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlParseEngine - parse() - HQL: from CartManData.Domain.Publisher pub
2012-08-22 16:22:28,174 [15] DEBUG NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
2012-08-22 16:22:28,200 [15] DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache - unable to locate HQL query plan in cache; generating (from CartManData.Domain.Publisher pub)
2012-08-22 16:22:28,201 [15] DEBUG NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlParseEngine - parse() - HQL: from CartManData.Domain.Publisher pub
2012-08-22 16:22:28,202 [15] DEBUG NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
2012-08-22 16:22:28,206 [15] DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan - enumerable: from CartManData.Domain.Publisher pub
2012-08-22 16:22:28,208 [15] DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.QueryParameters - named parameters: {}
2012-08-22 16:22:28,210 [15] DEBUG rollingFile - End of retrieval
```

Comment: What does your `PublisherRepository.GetByName()` look like? And how do you get your `session` object?

Comment: Hi Miroslav - the Session object is retrieved via a HttpModule, where the session object is bound to CurrentSessionContext.  That seems to be working fine as if you check to see if session is open, it reports it is.
  
PublisherRepository.GetByName() looks like this:

`using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Publisher))
                    .Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Eq("Name", name))
                    .UniqueResult<Publisher>();
            }`

Comment: So basically, your query works when you are using Criteria API, but when you replace it with LINQ or HQL query, it doesn't even hit the DB? Strange...

Comment: @PoorbandTony: which Nhibernate version are you using?

Comment: do you have second level caching enabled?

Comment: @LeftyX it's 3.3.1.4000.  {at]Firo no tried both with and without.  It's very odd  - going to try it in a blank solution and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: @PoorbandTony: could you please give us some feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have problems with your mappings.
I've tried to recreate your situation and I have changed your hbm files a little bit

**Publisher**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="CartManData"
                   namespace="CartManData.Domain">

    <class name="Publisher" lazy="false">
        <id name="Id">
            <generator class="guid"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="Name"></property>
        <property name="AddressLine1"></property>
        <property name="AddressLine2"></property>
        <property name="AddressLine3"></property>
        <property name="Town"></property>
        <property name="PostCode"></property>
        <property name="Telephone"></property>
        <property name="Email"></property>
        <property name="Enabled"></property>
        <property name="CommissionRate"></property>

        <set name="Coupons" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="false">
            <key column="PublisherId" />
            <one-to-many class="CartManData.Domain.Coupon, CartManData" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Coupon**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="CartManData"
                   namespace="CartManData.Domain">

    <class name="Coupon">
        <id name="Id">
            <generator class="guid"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="Name"></property>
        <property name="EffectiveFrom"></property>
        <property name="EffectiveTo"></property>
        <property name="UnitPrice"></property>
        <property name="OriginalPrice"></property>
        <property name="CouponImage"></property>
        <property name="Enabled"></property>

        <many-to-one class="CartManData.Domain.Publisher, CartManData" name="Publisher">
            <column name="PublisherId" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

As you can see I've used a **many-to-one** relationship on Coupon.
You can read how these relationships work [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arnona/archive/2011/07/12/understanding-one-to-many-relationships-in-nhibernate.aspx)
I've used the inverse="true" in the set defined for the Publisher mapping. Some more information about [inverse](http://notherdev.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/nhibernates-inverse-what-does-it-really.html).

If you want to have a look at the 2 classes:

```
public class Publisher
{
    public Publisher()
    {
        this.Coupons = new HashSet<Coupon>();
    }

    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Town { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Telephone { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal CommissionRate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Coupon
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EffectiveFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EffectiveTo { get; set; }
    public virtual double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual double OriginalPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual string CouponImage { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public virtual Publisher Publisher { get; set; }

}
```

You can download a working example (**NHVariousTests**) [here](https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=669ADF1AF64DF389&resid=669ADF1AF64DF389%21207&authkey=AL1RQQ1kD9MMNMg).

Comment: Better late than never - only over 6 years too late! :)  (apologies)